# apply.quarterly different behavior on different computers/worksessions

Tags: r, xts

I have a daily xts with 8 columns. 
Yesterday, I used `apply.quarterly(xts, last)` and received the last value (each quarter) for all columns. 
Today, the same code produces different results: it takes the last value (each quarter) for the last (most right) column.

I double-checked this at a friend's computer:

```
require(quantmod)
asd=getSymbols('AAPL', auto.assign = F)
apply.quarterly(asd, last)
```

On his computer, the function returns all columns, each quarter. On my computer, it returns only the last column.

Any idea why this is so? (And especially why my own results can be different from one session to another - without updating anything?)
Is `to.period` a safer option?

Comment: Do you by any chance have `data.table` loaded too in your session when you try to do this?  Both `xts` and `data.table` have `last` functions, and sometimes I've had them 'clash'.

Comment: Thanks!!! It was not `data.table` but `dplyr`. Solved :-)

Comment: @FXQuantTrader: `data.table` is usually careful to check if `xts` is also loaded, so it's likely not an issue. `dplyr::lag` is not so friendly.